# Pattern in remainders of $n \pmod{2}$, $n \pmod{3}$, ..., $n \pmod{n-1}$

Tags: number-theory

Taking a look at the remainders of an integer $n\pmod{k}$, where $k$ ranges from $1$ to $n$, I noticed that it follows a pattern. It's probably already known but I couldn't find anything about it on internet so I thought it was worth sharing. The pattern follows like this:

Let $M$ denote the group of integers ranging from $1$ to $\sqrt{n}$, $M_{i}$ is the $ith$ element of this group (where $M_{1} = 1$); Let $Q_{i}$ denote the quotient of $n/M_{i}$. Then:  $$n \equiv r\pmod{M_{i}},$$ 
and, for all integer values of $j$, ranging from $0$ to $(Q_i-Q_{(i+1)}-1)$, the following congruence holds:
$$n \equiv r+(j*i)\pmod{Q_{i}-j}$$

Comment: May I ask what this mysterious $r$ is?

Comment: @awllower It's just the remainder we get by dividing $n/M_i$. For instance, lets take $31$; The integer part of its square is $5$, therefore $i$ ranges from $1$ to $5$; Lets then get $Q3$ and $Q4$.
$$Q_{4}=31/M_{4} \equiv 31/4=7$$
$$Q_{3}=31/M_{3} \equiv 31/3=10$$
For $i=3$, $j$ ranges from $0$ to $Q_{3}−Q_{4}−1 \equiv 10−7−1 = 2$
$$31 \equiv r = 1 \pmod{M_{3}}$$
$$31 \equiv 1+0∗3 \equiv 1 \pmod{Q_{3}-0}$$
$$31 \equiv 1+1∗3 \equiv 1+3 \equiv 4 \pmod{Q_{3}-1}$$
$$31 \equiv 1+2∗3 \equiv 1+6 \equiv 7 \pmod{Q_{3}-2}$$

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @LucasDaSilvaPereira your observation is interesting. Long time ago I was playing also with the same congruences you use for other kind of tests. Maybe the results might give you ideas, so just in case: http://hobbymaths.blogspot.jp/2015/03/algorithm-to-find-bounds-of-godbachs.html